# Fit a row in latex table

Tags: tables

I have this latex table:

```
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{ c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c }
 C & C & A & T & C & G & C & A & C & T & C & C & G & A & T & G & T & G & G & C & C & G & G & T & G & C & T & C & A & C & G & T & T & G & C & C & T \\
 
\end{tabular}
}
```

And this is how it looks:
[image]

how can I set the the table, so this row will all be in 1 line (you can see that in the current situation, there are 2 lines

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You don't have enough columns in your table.  Adding 5 more `c` or, if I counted right, replacing all the `c c c...` by `*{37}{c}` should work.  But do you really need a table?

Comment: Don't ignore errors. You are declaring a tabular with 32 columns and trying to use 37.

Comment: thanks for the comments, it works now

Answer (score 1):

Maybe off-topic respect the tabular problem, but really you want to type DNA sequences typing `C & C & A & T & ...` ?

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dnaseq,seqsplit,xcolor,booktabs}

\renewcommand{\DNAblock}{3}
\renewcommand{\DNAreserve}{0}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}

\caption{My DNA sequence 1}
\centering
\renewcommand{\seqinsert}{\ifmmode\allowbreak\else{\,}\fi}
\begin{tabular}{c}\toprule
\seqsplit{CCATCGCACTCCGATGTGGCCGGTGCTCACGTTGCCT}
\\\bottomrule   
\end{tabular}

\caption{My DNA sequence 2}
\renewcommand{\DNAblock}{1}
\renewcommand{\DNAreserve}{1}
\centering\footnotesize
\begin{minipage}{.93\linewidth}
\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{1pt}
\DNA!CCATCGCACTCCGATGTGGCCGGTGCTCACGTTGCCT !
\\[-4ex]\rule{\linewidth}{1pt}
\end{minipage}


\caption{My DNA sequence 3}
\normalsize
\renewcommand{\DNAblock}{3}
\renewcommand{\DNAreserve}{0000}
\centering
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{1pt}
\DNA!
CCATCG'{yellow!50}CAC'{white}TCCGATGTG
GCCGGTGCTCACGTTGCCTCGGTGCTCACGTTGCCT 
CCATC'{yellow!50}CAC'{white}TCCGATGTGGC 
CCATCGCACTCCGATGTGGCCGGTGCTCACGTTGCCT 
CCATCGC'{red!20}ACTCCGATG'{white}GGCCGGTGC 
CCATCGCACTCCGATGTGGCCGGTGCTCACGTTGCC 
!
\\[-5pt]\rule{\linewidth}{1pt}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```